# What analytics model/classifier should be used to predict price?

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

I've go dataset with more than 10 features - football skills describing players. There is also price value in each row. I would like to predict price by specifying features (skills). Initially I used linear regression, but it looks like it's not a good choice because:

- price is high if only three skills are high (pace, goalkeeper, passing) for goalkeeper
- price is high if defender, pace, playmaker and technique are high for defender
- price is high if striker, technique and pace are high together for striker

etc... so it's not just linear dependency because not all skills should be considered for goalkeepers, defenders etc. Specific combination of skills makes the price high. I don't know how to tackle this and predict price by providing skills (all 10+). Do you maybe have ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can try to feed them into deep neural n. (or MLP) . By doing so you can discover nonlinear dependencies.

Comment: I would create different models for for each position (a linear mode fore goalkeepers, a linear model for defenders, etc.) and see if that works. If not, you can try as suggested try a neural network (look up `keras`).